# Disable woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to prevent woocommerce  from updating the user meta (saved billing and shipping user addresses) in the checkout if the user enters a different address.

in class-wc-checkout.php there is a woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data filter which is set to true, but I need to know how to override this and set it to false.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much

Luke

Comment: Have you tried `remove_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', 'update_user_meta' );`? Actually...what have you tried? It sounds like you understand what's going on. I'd assume you've tried some things.

Comment: Or `add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );`

Did the trick!  Thanks @helgatheviking