# Disable user profile update when data already exist after Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I have a store where users have data registered in the profile. In the checkout page there is the possibility to change the data that is automatically filled (pull of the profile).

I would like: if for example the customer enters another address or another email, that this data would NOT be saved in the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will disable the user profile to be updated if the data already exist when an order is placed *(see in `WC_Checkout` `process_customer()` method [source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#1004-1030))*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', 'checkout_update_customer_data_callback', 10, 2 );
function checkout_update_customer_data_callback( $boolean, $checkout ) {
    if ( get_current_user_id() > 0 ) {
        $customer = new WC_Customer( get_current_user_id() );
        $first_name = $customer->get_first_name();

        // When customer data already exist, don't update it when an order is processed
        if ( ! empty( $first_name ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $boolean;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Related: [Disable woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815379/disable-woocommerce-checkout-update-customer-data/26816779#26816779)